# REPL unresponsive after closing window created by SDL 2 (using cl-sdl2)

Tags: common-lisp, sdl-2, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to create a window using [cl-sdl2](https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2).

My code works - it creates a window for 2 seconds, and then closes it:

```
(defun main ()
  (sdl2:with-init (:everything)
                  (sdl2:with-window (win :title "cl-sdl2 sample" :flags '(:shown :fullscreen))
                                    (let ((surf (sdl2:get-window-surface win)))
                                      (sdl2:fill-rect surf nil (sdl2:map-rgb (sdl2:surface-format surf) #xff #xff #xff))
                                      (sdl2:update-window win)
                                      (sdl2:delay 2000)))))

(main)
```

However, after the window closes, the repl (CCL) becomes stuck. I can no longer evaluate expressions. **Why is this, and how do I get back to a functioning repl?**

As it stands, I have to keep spawning new CCL repl processes every time I run the sample to test it, which is quickly becoming tedious.

I'm on MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue with cl-sdl2 as seen here: https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2/issues/89

The current proposed workaround is to move the repl thread off of the main thread and connect to that via swank/slime on a seperate terminal, then run the sdl program on the main thread. An example is shown below.

```
(bt:make-thread (lambda () (swank:create-server :port 4005 :dont-close t)))
(sdl2:make-this-thread-main (lambda () (sdl2.kit:start)))
```